# load option id from database on image click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im trying to think of the best way to do this and im coming up short... I have a dropdown menu which pulls names from a database. Something like this -

```
<form class="option1">
<select name="users" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="0">NAMES:</option>
<option value="1">John</option>
<option value="2">Mark</option>
<option value="3">Luke</option>
<option value="4">Chris</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Then I have a javascript function that gets a php file which connects to a database and displays the records. The dropdown is fine, but id like to be able to have this happen when someone clicks an image. Can I just assign an option value to the image, then do something like -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('img').click(function(){
$('select').val($(this).attr('option'));
});
});
```

to make it fire when a certain tile is clicked? Any ideas? thanks all.

Comment: Did you try it to see if it works ?

Comment: @adeneo.. Im trying it now, I suppose what I was asking was if this is how that particular function could / should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of two possibilities:

1) use the alt-attribute to store the id in the image tag:

```
<img src="img.png" alt="1">
```

then you could use

```
$('select').val($(this).attr('alt'));
```

2) use the id of the image to store the id of the users in the DB:

```
<img id="img_1" src="img.png">
```

then you could use

```
$('select').val(this.id.substr(-1));
```

Comment: store in `data-` attribute and no need to parse ID and can leave `alt` for it's intended purpose,  read with `jQuery.data()`

Comment: didn't know if new html5 features were an option. using data- would be the most elegant solution but might not support all browsers.